# ColdFusion ORM: Table/View does not exist

Tags: object, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've created a simple ColdFusion 9 ORM test as follows.

Application.cfc:

```
component {
  this.ormenabled = "true";
  this.datasource = "cfartgallery";
  this.ormsettings.logSQL = "true";
  }
```

State.cfc:

```
component persistent="true" {
  property name="state_code" type="string" fieldtype="id";
  property name="state_name" type="string" fieldtype="column";
  }
```

index.cfm:

```
<cfscript>
ormreload();
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#EntityLoad("State")#" />
```

Upon calling index.cfm I get the following error:

```
Error while loading the entity.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'State' does not exist.

The error occurred in D:/WebDocs/tada/data/misc/basicorm/index.cfm: line 62
60 : </cfscript>
61 : 
62 : <cfdump var="#EntityLoad("State")#" />
```

However, if I change index.cfm to use cfquery, shown below, a recordset is returned as expected without error.

```
<cfquery name="getstates" datasource="cfartgallery">
  SELECT * FROM State
</cfquery>
```

I know that State.cfc is being processed because I can change the file to cause errors. Can anyone think of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's some plural/singular assumptions made, try setting a table hint in the state.cfc to component persistent = true table = "State" {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the `dbcreate` setting for [ORM config](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSED380324-6CBE-47cb-9E5E-26B66ACA9E81.html).  Either set it to `update` or `dropcreate`.  By default ORM will not create new or update tables based on persistent CFCs.

Comment: I thought it was odd given that cfartgallery doesn't contain a *State* table by default. But then the OP said they were able to query it manually so it must have existed. Perhaps they just needed to ormReload() after manually adding it? You don't need `dbcreate` for ORM to be able to use existing tables.